# some OpenGL functionality not available

Tags: opengl, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-12.04

I have some problems. I using ubuntu 12.04 and this is result of `fglrxinfo` command:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11627 Compatibility Profile Context
```

but OpenGL version 2 and above functionality such as `shaders` not available. Should i update my device driver? or something else?

Comment: What is the output of `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` from your application?

Comment: Also, how are you determining they are not available?

Comment: 'glCreateShader' not available in development files.

Comment: 'glCreateShader' also not available from extenion(glext.h) development file

Comment: Maybe you could post some of your OpenGL initialization code. Maybe a minimally functional example or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a FAQ. The X11/GLX OpenGL ABI only specifies entry points up to OpenGL-1.2 (right now a new ABI is in the works). This means, to access anything beyond OpenGL-1.2 the advenced functionality must be loaded through the *extension mechanism*.

Since you're on Unbuntu here are step by step instructions to get this as painless as possible:

1. `sudo apt-get install libglew-dev`
2. In all your projects source files replace `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <GL/glew.h>`
3. Right after the OpenGL context has been created, for example after `glutCreateWindow` call `glewInit()` and check its error code (must return GLEW_OK).